# why i am getting "get-content error" while creating new file through terminal?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

why iam getting "get-content error" while creating new file via terminal ?

```js
PS D:\playground> type nul >index.html
Get-Content: Cannot find path 'D:\playground\nul' because it does not exist.
PS D:\playground>
```

Comment: this is a `cmd` command in a PowerShell shell.

Comment: ```type``` in PowerShell is an alias for the ```Get-Content``` cmdlet, so you're really doing ```Get-Content nul >index.html```, but there's no file called ```nul``` in the current directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean something like:

```
echo $null > file
dir file


    Directory: C:\users\admin\foo


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         5/30/2022   7:25 PM              2 file
```